# Pass rails variable to ajax in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to rails. I am trying to use ajax and call a controller method. The controller method creates an instance variable which I presume is available to success callback in ajax.

However, whenever I run the code, JS console gives "test_array is null" error. Please suggest a solution and an insight into what is happening. The code is as follows.

I have thoroughly researched this issue on internet (including SO) but none of the answers seem to be fitting my problem.

sentiscores_controller.rb

```
def render_phrase
@tag_cloud_temp = [{text: 'Hello', weight: 1000},{text: 'World!', weight: 1100}]
end
```

index.html.erb

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/sentiscores/render_phrase',
        data: {'senti_score': 5},
        success: function(){
        var test_array = <%= raw @tag_cloud_temp.to_json%>;
        console.log(test_array[0]['text']);
        },
        error: function(exception){
        console.log("Error! : "+exception);
        }
       })
```

The actual html source code looks like the following

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/sentiscores/render_phrase',
            data: {'senti_score': 5},
            success: function(){
                    var test_array = null;
                    console.log(test_array[0]['text']);
                    },
             error: function(exception){console.log("Error! : "+exception);}
                })
```

Comment: What's the output if you just log the full array? `console.log(test_array)`

Comment: What does the actual resulting JavaScript code look like?

Comment: @jon1467 if i log the full array it gives - null on the JS console.

Comment: @AndEnthu: Please include relevant code *in the question* and then indicate that the question has been updated *after* doing so.

Comment: @David have added the html source code. Also, the ajax function is getting called as response to a click of a stacked bar chart using highcharts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your controller, you'll want to `render` the JSON back to the AJAX call, like this:

```
# controller method    
@tag_cloud_temp = [{text: 'Hello', weight: 1000},{text: 'World!', weight: 1100}] 

render json: {
  tag_cloud_temp: @tag_cloud_temp
}
```

Then, in your AJAX call, you'll want to recieve the `data` from that `render`, like this:

```
// in ajax call
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

If you look at the `data` object, you should see the information from your controller.

Comment: Good answer. I was typing just about the exact same thing when you posted. I was also going to comment on why the OP can't use `<%= raw @tag_cloud_temp.to_json%>` on the client side since this seems to be a common source of confusion. Anyways, nice!

Comment: Ah, thanks and yeah that is a good point of learning, too, for sure!

Comment: @JonathanBowman I made the modification suggested by you. The message that I now get is <unavailable> on JS console.

Comment: @AndEnthu Weird, I haven’t seen it say unavailable before...it should say undefined if that variable doesn’t exist. What browser are you using? Are you using the standard console or a third-party debugging tool? Also, just try it in another browser, using the built in console to see if you get anything different.

Comment: @JonathanBowman...i was earlier trying on firefox, now i tried on chrome...now i see the object..thanks for helping

Comment: Great! No problem and glad to help.